# Regex to identify Clock Speed from a String in Groovy

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have this String `2 Intel(R)  Itanium(R)  Processor 9320s (1.66 GHz, 16 MB)` I need to get **1.66 GHz** which could be any thing a clock speed has like `1600 MHz` or `1.33 GHz` etc

Any Help?

I was trying something like `\b\([\d\s\w\.]*,\b` Please give your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with Pattern class:

```
"\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\s*.?Hz"
```

It will search for a decimal number, followed by optional spaces, and an optional multiplier (I use any character in the regex - since I only need to match it), and ends with "Hz".

Comment: @AbhishekSimon: I was fixing things around, it should be working now.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = '''2 Intel(R) Itanium(R) Processor 9320s (1.66 GHz, 16 MB)'''
extractedStr = str.replaceAll(/(.*)\((.*)Hz,(.*)/,'$2Hz')
println extractedStr
```

Here we split the portion of input string into three parts,

- everything that falls before `(xxxx yHz` will be in the first (.*) part of the regex. This first part can be accessed by $1.
- `\(` is the open brace before clock speed. `\` is to escape `(`
- (.*)Hz, that follows contains the clock speed value with units and comma. This second portion of (.*) can be accessed by $2.
- The third (.*) is for everything that follows the , after clock speed. Can be accessed by $3.

As per this, $2Hz is all we need to extract the clock speed out of your string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like so: `\s+\((.+?), .+?\)$`. This will extract the values within the last set of brackets and throw the first value (in your case, the `1.66 GHz`) in a regex group which you can later access to extract the value.

You can then check [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+5+-+Capturing+regex+groups) tutorial for more information on how to match and access regex groups in groovy.

Answer (score 0):

This will find clock speed and not requires parentheses:

```
"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)\\s*.Hz"
```

The group 1 will contain the number itself